# Add new key-value represented by a `Pair` to a `MutableMap`

Tags: kotlin

I currently have this class with `dsl` like building ability

```
class GRLMessage {
    var headerMap : MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf()
    lateinit var methodType : GRLMethod
    lateinit var multipartObject : IGRLMultipart

    fun message(closure: GRLMessage.() -> Unit) : GRLMessage {
        closure()
        return this
    }

    fun method(closure: GRLMessage.() -> GRLMethod) : GRLMessage {
        methodType = closure()
        return this
    }

    fun headers(closure: GRLMessage.() -> Unit) : GRLMessage {
        closure()
        return this
    }

    fun header(closure: GRLMessage.() -> Pair<String, String>) : GRLMessage {
        var pair = closure()
        headerMap.put(pair.first, pair.second)
        return this
    }

    fun multipart(closure: GRLMessage.() -> IGRLMultipart) : GRLMessage {
        multipartObject = closure()
        return this
    }
}
```

And I test it like this

```
class GRLMessageTest {

    data class DummyMultipart(val field: String) : IGRLMultipart {
        override fun getContent() {
            this
        }
    }

    @Test fun grlMessageBuilderTest() {
        val grlMessage = GRLMessage().message {
            method { GRLMethod.POST }
            headers {
                header { Pair("contentType", "object") }
                header { Pair("objectType", "DummyMultipart") }
            }
            multipart { DummyMultipart("dummy") }
        }

        val multipart = DummyMultipart("dummy")
        val headers = mapOf(
                Pair("contentType", "object"),
                Pair("objectType", "DummyMultipart")
        )
        val method = GRLMethod.POST

        assertEquals(multipart, grlMessage.multipartObject)
        assertEquals(method, grlMessage.methodType)
        assertEquals(headers, grlMessage.headerMap)
    }
}
```

But despite providing

```
header { Pair("contentType", "object") }
```

I still have to evaluate `closure` inside `header` method and directly `put` key and value into my `MutableMap`

```
fun header(closure: GRLMessage.() -> Pair<String, String>) : GRLMessage {
    var pair = closure()
    headerMap.put(pair.first, pair.second)
    return this
}
```

Is there a better way adding entries to `Map`?

Comment: Did you try `headerMap += pair`?

Comment: I got `Assignment operators ambiguity`

Comment: I believe that is because your `headerMap` is a `var` instead of a `val`.

Comment: Also, anywhere you are using `Pair("Some Text", "Some Other Text")` you could just use `"Some Text" to "Some Other Text"`

Comment: I thought `val` was read-only or that applies only to reference?

Comment: Only to the reference. It's a `MutableMap` so it can be changed, you just can't replace it with another map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your `headerMap` need to be a var? If not, you can change it to a val and use `headerMap += closure()`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) makes your fluent methods more obviously fluent:

```
fun <T: Any> T.fluently(func: ()->Unit): T {
    return this.apply { func() } 
}
```

With that your fluent function is always clear about its return:

```
fun header(closure: GRLMessage.() -> Pair<String, String>) : GRLMessage {
    return fluently { headerMap += closure() }
}
```

Which is really the same as:

```
fun header(closure: GRLMessage.() -> Pair<String, String>) : GRLMessage {
    return this.apply { headerMap += closure() }
}
```

But the extension function adds a touch of readability.

Above I use the answer given in by @Ruckus for solving your specific question of adding a `Pair` to the `headerMap`.  But you have other options that you might want to know about for other use cases of your DSL...

You can use [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html), [`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) or [`with`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html) which would allow any type of decomposition of the results of `closure()` call (maybe it is more complicated than `Pair` in the future).  All of these are basically the same, *minus their resulting value*:

```
with(closure()) { headerMap.put(this.first, this.second) }
closure().apply { headerMap.put(this.first, this.second) }
closure().let { headerMap.put(it.first, it.second) }
```

Using `let` or `apply` is nice if you want to handle a case where `closure()` allows nullable return, in which case you might want to take action only if not `null`:

```
closure()?.apply { headerMap.put(this.first, this.second) }
closure()?.let { headerMap.put(it.first, it.second) }
```

**Other notes about your code:**

- use `val` instead of `var` unless you have no other choice
- `lateinit` (or the similar `Delegates.notNull()`) seem dangerous to use in an uncontrolled lifecycle where there is no guarantee it will be completed, because the error message will be confusing and happen at some unexpected time in the future.  There are likely other ways to solve this with a DSL that chains calls to create more of a multi-step grammar
- You can shorten code by only having types on one side of the assignment, for example:

  ```
  val myMap = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  var myMap : MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf()
  ```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `fluently` function? Why not just use `apply` since that's all `fluently` does?

Comment: because one is self evident as to the intent and the other doesn't.

Comment: Fair enough. I was wondering if there was something more subtle I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Well for now as a solution I created extension for `MutableMap`

```
fun MutableMap<String, String>.put(pair : Pair<String, String>) {
    this.put(pair.first, pair.second)
}
```

Which allowed me to write like this

```
fun header(closure: GRLMessage.() -> Pair<String, String>) : GRLMessage {
    headerMap.put(closure())
    return this
}
```